# Cant post data in body in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

iam trying to post the following json data

```
{"name":"somename","email":"somemail","password":"abcdef"}
```

in the body of my api,

```
<?php


require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && 
isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is 
missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

my problem is that `if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && 
isset($_POST['password']))` is always false and the message`Required parameters (name, email or password) is 
missing! is shown`

In the wampserver log, error is given as

> PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: `"password","abcdef"` should be a colon like the others, *n'est-ce pas?* Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46042691/1

Comment: yes, that was a type error

Comment: where's the html/form for this?

Comment: i was using postman to post the data

Comment: All I can ask now is; what version of php are you using? If you're using 7, you can't use it/rely on that anymore http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php and also states: *"In general, php://input should be used instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA. "*

Comment: iam using php version 5.6.25, iam actually new to php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153640/discussion-between-navneet-krishna-and-fred-ii).

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, it worked by adding like this $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked out for you, *cheers*

Comment: I posted a community wiki answer that you can mark off as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is a community wiki answer.

As per the manual on `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

> "In general, php://input should be used instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.".

As noted by the OP in comments also:

> @Fred-ii- thanks, it worked by adding like this $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

Answer (score 1):

if sending post data as json, in api you must decode input data to array

`$data = json_decode($_POST)`

and after then continue with the condition

`if (isset($data['name'], $data['email'], $data['password']) {`